# Is the Meta blog link intended to be Stack Overflow's blog?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, blog, meta, hyperlinks

Now that we've got our blog rolling along well, we link to it at the bottom. But only on the main site. On the Meta site, it's linking to the Stack Overflow (and thus, more accurately, Stack Exchange) blog.

I can see reason for linking to the latter - on Meta, we discuss many of the elements that end up on the blog. However, it's fairly divergent from how every other link at the bottom is the same whether you're on the Main or the Meta.

Is it intended that the blog link differs here?

Comment: I actually have written a Recent Changes post (not yet published) from the SU blog. We could post something similar on Gaming, though its obviously not the same as the main SE blog.

Comment: @Ivo It could be simply the way I view the blog, but in the same vein that I'm not particularly fond of using the sidebar ads for the Q&A engine tools, I'm somewhat unkeen on using the blog as a venue for updates on the Stack Exchange engine. That's just my take, though.

Comment: I don't see it as purely updates on the SE engine, but rather informing the community of important changes that affect how they use the site. Besides, while part of the goal of the blog is to promote the site's content, it is there *for* users *by* users. So if we get more votes or suddenly everyone can edit, that can be useful to point out to those who don't venture much further than Meta.Gaming.

Comment: @Ivo I'm not assuming you intend it purely for that, either. My own interpretation was: for *gamers*, by *gamers*. We're indeed users as much as we are gamers, and all due in part to being gamers, but I've always pictured it as being focused on more of the gaming and primary site content aspect, moreso than the background Meta stuff that the Meta site is for. Again, though, my take - I haven't even written anything for the blog, nevermind been all that contributatory towards its organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, I changed it on meta as well.

edit: this is now *intentional*, see

[Can a new official blog post also be announced on sites with their own blogs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101104/can-a-new-official-blog-post-also-be-announced-on-sites-with-their-own-blogs)